# Get full slug for a Wordpress Post

Tags: functions, loop

I am using this code to get the URL of a post which is subsequently used as input on a form field.

```
 global $post;$post_slug = $post->post_name;$post_slug = urlencode($post_slug);
```

However, this code doesn't return the category of the post.

Comment: Why not [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)?

Comment: how would that be incorporated in my code above ? This is outside the loop and the variable $post is defined as global.

Comment: `global $post; get_permalink($post);` should work